# Tornado raise gen.Return Return None

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to learn tornado coroutines, but I have error using below code.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 124, in args_kwargs
    raise gen.Return(kwargs)
 enter code here
Return
```

code:

```
from tornado import gen

class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def args_kwargs(self,pro):
        try:
            kwargs = self.get_argument("data",None)
            if kwargs:
                raise gen.Return(kwargs)
        except Exception,e:
            print e


class EventAPIHandler(BaseHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        try:
            re = yield self.args_kwargs("event")
            if re:
                self.write(re)
                self.finish()
        except Exception,e:
            print e
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if `self.get_argument("data",None)` returns `None`. Then `kwargs` is `None`, so `args_kwargs` doesn't execute `raise gen.Return(kwargs)`.

Therefore, since `args_kwargs` doesn't raise `gen.Return` nor an exception, it returns `None`. Then `re` is `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`gen.Return` is an exception, so it's getting caught by the blanket `except Exception, e:` clause. You'll need to either narrow the `except` clause or special-case `gen.Return`:

```
except gen.Return:
    raise
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```